# How to get commit_id and branch information in airflow

Tags: python, airflow

After the gitlab code was merged, airflow dag was triggered, how to get the commit_id and branch information of gitlab merged this time

Comment: Hi junwei ning, could you give more detail about your situation? For example, what code do you want to merge? How gitlab triggers Airflow?

Comment: Hi  EvensF.  Now there is a demand. When code A is merged in my gitlab project, commit_id is B. I can trigger airflow dag instances through webhooks. I hope to get this commit_id in my dag code and get the commit branch. This way I can accurately download the code of the node whose commit_id is B in dag

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible. There are few reasons for that.

First of all, this is the question of how you bring your files to Airflow. IT's really the question of your deployment, not Airflow itself. This is not something is readily available in Airflow. All that Airflow cares about is the file is there in the designated DAG folder. The concept of DAG versioning where Airflow will know and care about different DAG versions is still in "draft" form https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-36+DAG+Versioning  and will likely change. But it's not implemented. You might want to rely on some properties of your deployment - for example if you bring the DAGs via GitSync, you can run git command in the DAG to determine the git commit based on the presence of the local `.git` folder with the information. However this has no chances of working currently (Airflow 2.1) anyway.

The main reason why it cannot be done, is that Airflow currently completely decouples DAG parsing from DAG execution. Parser and scheduler work completely independently from triggering a DAG, so when you trigger the DAG, the parser might not yet have "parsed" the new DAG version, or it could even be not-yet-synced by your GitSync process for example. Worse than that - the scheduler and parser work continuously while the DAG is processed and it might well be that when new version of the DAG comes, subsequent tasks from that DAG will be scheduled using the NEWER version of the DAG. So yeah - the DAG structure MIGHT change while the DAG Run is executed. Worse than that - if the worker manages to sync the new DAG version before it starts executing them, the worker might use different version of the DAG than when scheduler parsed it and scheduled. So you are never able to pin the whole DAG execution  or even single task to a particular commmit SHA of the DAG as it might dynamically change during the whole commit -> parse -> schedule -> execute cycle.

Until DAG Versioning is fully hashed out and implemented, this is a known "property" of Airflow DAGs. The DAGs are supposed to change "Slowly" - if you want to make substantial changes to DAG structure, you should rather create a new DAG than  modify existing one.

Comment: oh i see，Which future version can get the commit id and branch information through webhooks?  Is there a plan?I think this is a good feature.

Comment: no firm plans yet, 2.3 likely ut that's a guess.

Comment: But if you would like to contribute and speed it up - feel free :). Airflow is created by community and anyone can help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it is very helpful to me

Comment: If I want to get the commit_id information in webhooks, which piece of code should I modify?

Comment: Again - this is not really possible. You might write your own callbacks on failure/on success and write your own webhooks there if you want. no special need to change airflow code for that - and you can retrieve the information from local .git if you synchronise it with DAGs in your custom code (but it has cavets I explained above)

Comment: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.10/airflow/models/dag.py#L172